# Get the file extension in the JavaScript

Tags: javascript, file, file-extension

I have a problem checking what is an extension in my multiple input files. I am added `pathinfo` in the javascript and alert to check the file extension, but cannot work. Below is my coding:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>



<input type="file" name="vasplus_multiple_files" id="vasplus_multiple_files"   accept="application/msword, application/pdf, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,image/*" multiple="multiple"/>
    <input type="submit" name="next" class="action-button" value="Submit" onclick="sendFunc_web()"/> 
<script>
function sendFunc_web(){
                var inp = document.getElementById('vasplus_multiple_files');
                var count = inp.files.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < inp.files.length; ++i) {
                    var num = i+1;
                    var name = inp.files.item(i).name;      
                    var ext = pathinfo(name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);   
                     alert("here is a file path: " + ext);
                                
                }

        }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

For example, if the file names are abcdefg.pdf and haha.jpeg, I want to alert twice data to show extensions are `pdf` and jpeg``.

The result might be like below the pictures;

[image: output 1]

[image: output 2]

Hope someone can guide me which part I am getting wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the name file by dot, and access last index:

```js
function sendFunc_web() {
  var inp = document.getElementById('vasplus_multiple_files');
  var count = inp.files.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < inp.files.length; ++i) {
    var num = i + 1;
    var name = inp.files.item(i).name;
    console.log(name)
    let ext = ext[ext.length - 1]
    console.log(ext)
  }
}
```

Comment: It will not work when the file name contains more then one dots. so, you need to take file name like this  ext = ext[ext.length - 1];

Comment: Msk Satheesh you're right, answer updated

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following solution

```js
function sendFunc_web() {
  var inp = document.getElementById('vasplus_multiple_files');
  var count = inp.files.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < inp.files.length; ++i) {
    var num = i + 1;
    var name = inp.files.item(i).name;
    var ext = name.split('.');
    ext = ext[ext.length - 1];
    alert("here is a file path: " + ext);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" name="vasplus_multiple_files" id="vasplus_multiple_files" accept="application/msword, application/pdf, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,image/*" multiple="multiple" />
<input type="submit" name="next" class="action-button" value="Submit" onclick="sendFunc_web()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

RegEx (Fast & Accurate) version of `pathInfo`:

```js
function pathInfo(s) {
    s=s.match(/(.*?\/)?(([^/]*?)(\.[^/.]+?)?)(?:[?#].*)?$/);
    return {path:s[1],file:s[2],name:s[3],ext:s[4]};
}
var sample='folder/myfolder/another/file.min.js?query=1';
var result=pathInfo(sample);
console.log(result);
/*
{
  "path": "folder/myfolder/another/",
  "file": "file.min.js",
  "name": "file.min",
  "ext": ".js"
}
*/
console.log(result.ext);
```

Answer (score 0):

Short one:

```
fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("."))
```